# iPad typing by itself

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I have an iPad that I've been using for 9 months or so already. And I was using it just today (reading an article from the Internet) it accidentally flops (forgive my English) over my chest but when I open it up for reading again it starts to type by itself or at least it will not respond when I touch a button on the screen for example.

I tried to turn it off (by pressing the two buttons) but once It shows the slider to finally turn it off. The slider does not badge at all. So, I forced to cancel the shutting down of my iPad and here it is again going back to typing by itself.

And I was looking in the Internet and lo behold I am not alone. There had already been many case like this and it looks it has no solution at all for the moment.

I am living in an island nation (actually group of islands) called Federated States of Micronesia and we bought it from the mainland (USA) and I know probably some of your suggestions would be to ask for replacement. However, it would take very long if ever I will be allowed to return it to them.

So, my question then is, does anybody has this similar experience or at least from someone that they know of? And is there any possible solution to this one?

It has almost the same problem as [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WETemUDnU0) except that mine does not open an application but keeps on typing by itself when the keyboard is up or it just simply freezes that no matter where I touch on the screen it does not respond except if I press the Home button.

Any good advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your voice dictation off ?

Comment: what is it typing anyway :) just garbage or ?

Comment: Just any character from the keyboard but mostly alphabets and its random.

Comment: You could try plugging it into iTunes, and restoring from backup.

Comment: If it's a software issue, that should fix it. If it's a hardware issue? Not so much. =P Good luck. (If it works, feel free to post the solution as an answer and accept it.)

Comment: Bring it to apple for a full refund mate

Answer (score 4):

If you are typing, and it is not responding, but yet it starts typing by itself afterward, this is probably the effect of a slow down of your CPU or running out of RAM. When this happens, the keyboard does not show a key clicked, or a word typed until after you actually tapped the key.

*In order to fix it*:: try shutting down all open apps by double-pressing the Home button, holding down one of the apps until little red badges pop-up on all of them, and tapping that little red badge on each app until they all disappear.

*Then do a hard restart*:: Hold down the Sleep and Home buttons until the device turns off, then hold the Sleep button until you get the boot screen to turn it back on.

Test it out. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

In newer versions of iOS, the method to shutting down applications has changed. Instead, your open applications appear as tiles that you may scroll left to right. Swipe each of these up to shut off all of your open apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not software! Hardware problem. Its either a problem with the digitizer ribbon cable and its connection or the tape is missing across the home button side of the digitizer and it is making contact with metal frame.  Reseting or reinstalling the os will NOT cure the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Shut down the Settings app, then all the other apps should work okay. There seems to be a problem with just that app. Unfortunately, you can't delete it and download a new one because it's an Apple app.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the most recent operating system that was downloaded from the cloud is corrupted. You must download the operating system by plugging the iPad into a computer where the operating system is downloaded as a zip file and unzipped in the computer and transferred to the iPad by Cable